# is it possible linear response photodiode amplifier using 2n3819

Tags: photodiode

[image: typical photodiode current linear response versus open circuit voltage]

[image]This is a typical jfet circuit to amplify the photodiode signal.
Is this simply the photovoltaic voltage generated by the photodiode?
My understanding is this is highly non-linear since the voltage increases across the diode, with increasing light level.
At very low light levels it is possible the diode remains only slightly more than zero bias.

I have used the AD743JNZ with no problems previously. It is now a rare and expensive item. 2 orders from ebay turned out to be fakes. Digikey, Farnell and RSonline all now have minimum order charges.

For an AC audio modulated light signal up to 3kHz, I have been trying a discrete jfet circuit. I am sure this is not a transimpedance configuration as in the opamp implementation which maintains zero bias across the diode via the large feedback resistor.
Is there a simple variation on this circuit that can do this with very low noise, very high sensitivity for only the AC signal required?

Comment: Yes, highly non-linear....not at all as linear as the "standard" transimpedance op-amp, where the diode is run at either 0V or at a fixed reverse-bias voltage. This circuit is really only useful for detecting **VERY LOW** light levels.

Comment: The nonlinearity might be an feature rather than a bug in this case since it is essentially logarithmic. It won't saturate, but the signal level will decrease with increasing ambient light level.

Answer (score 0):

3kHz is pretty pokey.

Maybe establish two separate feedback paths for AC and DC  using a couple BJTs for the DC path, with the  usual R and tiny SOT parallel C (for stability) to control the AC gain. Add a pole in the DC feedback to isolate it, well below the 3kHz (maybe 10Hz).

Early voltage will limit the maximum value of AC feedback resistor R.

Preferably run the PD in reverse bias mode to a negative supply rail to minimize capacitance.